# How to create ui-select in form programmatically

Tags: uicomponent, programmatically

[image: Replace this multi-select for this field like magento product configuration]

My code to generate the field multi-select

```
$fieldset->addField('multiselect2', 'multiselect', array(
            'label'     => __('Select Type2'),
            'class'     => 'required-entry',
            'required'  => true,
            'name'      => 'multi',
            'onclick' => "return false;",
            'onchange' => "return false;",
            'elementTmpl' => 'ui/grid/filters/elements/ui-select', // I try this, but not work
            'component' => 'Magento_Ui/js/form/element/ui-select', // I try this, but not work
            'value'  => '4',
            'values' => array(
                '-1'=> array(
                    'label' => 'Please Select..',
                    'value' => '-1'
                ),
                '1' => array(
                    'value'=> Cat::getOptionsToMultiselect(),
                    'label' => __('Category')
                ),
            'after_element_html' => '<small>Comments</small>'
        ));
```

Answer (score 0):

public function toOptionArray()

```
    $this->attributeOptionsList = [
        [
            'value' => ""Test 1"",
            ""label"" => ""Test 1"",
            ""__disableTmpl"" => 1,
            ""optgroup"" => [
                [
                    'value' => ""Test 1.1"",
                    ""label"" => ""Test 1.1"",
                    ""__disableTmpl"" => 1,
                ],
            ],
        ],
    ];
    return $this->attributeOptionsList;
```

You can refer to the details [here](https://www.magedelight.com/resources/steps-to-add-multi-select-ui-dropdown-in-ui-form-in-magento-2/)

Comment: I require to use ui-select without any ui-component.xml
Add this component to variable $form programmatically
\Magento\Framework\Data\Form $form